# How is it possible multiple signals can get into handler even when signal is disabled?

Tags: c, linux, signals, posix

So I have the following code segment as part of my program. Handler is the handler for the SIGALRM.

```
 static void handler(void)
 {
     //DISABLE SIGALRM
     sigset_t oldset;
    disable_sigalrm(&oldset);
        if(queue_length(&queue) == 0)
        {
           ucontext_t context;
           getcontext(&context);
           swapcontext(&context,&uctxt_main);    
        }
        else
        {
            //...
            //enable sigalarm
        }
  }
```

The program disable_sigalrm looks as follows:

```
void disable_sigalrm(sigset_t* oldset)
{   
sigset_t sset;

//Empty sset
if(sigemptyset(&sset) == -1)
{
    printf("Error in emptying the signal set.\n");
}
//Add SIGALRM to sset
if(sigaddset(&sset,SIGALRM) == -1)
{
    printf("Error in adding SIGALRM to the specified signal set.\n");
}

//Block any occurence of SIGALRM
if(sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK,&sset,oldset) == -1)
{
    printf("Error in adding the specified signal; set to the signal mask.\n ");
}
   }
```

Now when I run in the debugger even after the queue length reaches zero it keeps coming back to handler. 
Since the SIGALRM is disabled, the only explanation that makes sense is if there are multiple signals waiting to reach the handler. Is it possible that multiple signals can wait to run to the handler? If so how would you disable them running the handler?

Comment: Did you try to `strace` your program?

Comment: For a signal handler, `static void handler(void) {...}` should be `static void handler(int signum){...}` Your compiler should complain about this, given the right error/warning level.

Comment: Signal masks are context specific, and it looks like you're disabling the signal for that context, but then switching contexts.

Comment: @CaptainMurphy Thanks! I did try set it_interval members to 0  for the the timer that is sending the SIGALRM. So it still is giving me problem. Does setting it_interval members to 0 stop a timer?

Comment: Use [`timer_settime`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/timer_settime.2.html) with it_value zero to disarm a timer. Setting it_interval to 0 makes it fire one more time.